# Vector, assign() function Undefined Behavior

Tags: c++, stdvector

I am curious about; is assign() function in vector  causes an undefined behavior if we use like below;

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec{0xAB,0xBC,0xCD};
std::vector<unsigned char> vec2{0xAA,0xBB,0xCC};

vec.assign(vec2.begin(),vec2.begin()+ vec.size());
```

Comment: Why would it cause UB? Elements are copied from another vector, so i don't see any UB here.

Comment: as assign parameter i give vec.size() which is a same vector's size we try to assign

Comment: Well, if `vec` initially contained more items than `vec2`, then it would be UB.

Comment: `vec.size()` will be evaluated *before* `vec.assign()` is invoked.

Answer (score 1):

`vec.size()` returns the size of `vec` and as that happens to have the same size as `vec2`, there is no problem with your code (other than some obfuscation of course). Where the size came from does not matter. If `vec.size() == vec2.size() == 3` all the following will do the same:

```
vec.assign(vec2.begin(),vec2.begin()+ vec.size());
vec.assign(vec2.begin(),vec2.begin()+ vec2.size());
vec.assign(vec2.begin(),vec2.begin()+ 3);
auto x = vec2.size();
vec.assign(vec2.begin(),vec2.begin()+ x);
auto y = x + 42;
vec.assign(vec2.begin(),vec2.begin()+ y-42);
```

Of course using `vec.size()` when you mean `vec2.size()` is "wrong" in the sense that once the vectors have different size you will have undefined behavior for accessing either of the two vectors out-of-bounds.